# How can I prove the equations without KroneckerDelta or LeviCivitaTensor?

Tags: symbols, tensors

How can I prove the equations without KroneckerDelta or LeviCivitaTensor?

These 729 equations:[image]

81 equations[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to prove a relation between `KroneckerDelta` and `LeviCivitaTensor` without using`KroneckerDelta` and `LeviCivitaTensor`?

Answer (score 1):

One way is simply brute-force.

Here is some setup:

```
ϵ[i_, j_, k_] := Evaluate[LeviCivitaTensor[3]][[i, j, k]];
δ = KroneckerDelta;
i = Range[1, 3];
```

The variable i is just a list from 1 to 3, which is what each index can run over.  We can use `Outer` to build up the difference of the LHS and RHS and then use `AllTrue` to check that everybody is 0.

```
AllTrue[# == 0 &]@*Flatten@Outer[
δ[#1, #4] δ[#2, #5] δ[#3, #6]
+ δ[#2, #4] δ[#3, #5] δ[#1, #6]
+ δ[#3, #4] δ[#1, #5] δ[#2, #6]
- δ[#2, #4] δ[#1, #5] δ[#3, #6]
- δ[#1, #4] δ[#3, #5] δ[#2, #6]
- δ[#3, #4] δ[#2, #5] δ[#1, #6]
- ϵ[#1, #2, #3] ϵ[#4, #5, #6]
&, i, i, i, i, i, i]
```

A similar exercise for the 81 is

```
AllTrue[# == 0 &]@*Flatten@Outer[
  δ[#1, #3] δ[#2, #4] - δ[#1, #4] δ[#2, #3]
  - Sum[ϵ[#1, #2, k] ϵ[#3, #4, k], {k, i}]
  &, i, i, i, i]
```

There are other identities too, such as

```
AllTrue[# == 0 &]@*Flatten@Outer[
    2 δ[#1, #2] - Sum[ϵ[#1, j, k] ϵ[#2, j, k], {j, i}, {k, i}] &, i, i]
```

and

```
Sum[ϵ[ii, j, k] ϵ[ii, j, k], {ii, i}, {j, i}, {k, i}]
```

Comment: thanks.Can I use the same way to proof another 9 equations [Epsilon][[i,j,k]][Epsilon][[l,j,k]]=2[Delta] and the last one equation [Epsilon][[i,j,k]][Epsilon][[i,j,k]]=6?

Comment: Updated with the other identities.