# Contracting Levi-Civita

Tags: summation, tensors

I am trying to contract two Levi-Civita symbols in tensor format like so:

$\epsilon_{a b} \epsilon_{c d}$

This code generates the Levi-Civita:

```
n = 2;
LevCiv := LeviCivitaTensor[2, List];

listLevCiv := 
 Table[If[UnsameQ[LevCiv[[a, b]], 0], {ToString[LeCi[a, b]], 
    LevCiv[[a, b]]}] 
  , {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}]
TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listLevCiv], Null], 2], 
 TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
LevCiv // MatrixForm
```

I would like something of this form:

```
    Output = Simplify[
   Table[LevCiv[[a, b]]*LevCiv[[c, d]], {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}, {c, 1, 
     n}, {d, 1, n}]];
Output // MatrixForm
```

Does anyone have experience working with such tensors and how to generate one output please?

Thanks

Comment: Is what you're looking for `Outer[Times, LevCiv, LevCiv]`?

Comment: Also, you should turn `LevCiv :=` into `=`---no need to re-generate the tensor every time you want to mention it.

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138167/7936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this by using `TensorProduct` directly on your `LeviCivitaTensor`

```
TensorProduct[LeviCivitaTensor[2, List], LeviCivitaTensor[2, List]] // MatrixForm
```

or more concise

```
#\[TensorProduct]# &[LeviCivitaTensor[2]] // Normal // MatrixForm
```

The infix version of `TensorProduct` can be entered as <kbd>ESC</kbd>`t*`<kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks great. I hope it holds up when I perform metric tensor contractions on it. Thanks sir!